# Uninstall SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms, compatibility, uninstallation, sql-server-2016

I managed to install SSMS 2016 on Windows 7, but it doesn’t work of course.

I've tried to uninstall SQL Server 2016 using the SQL 2016 (un)install program in the Control Panel, but when I click remove it throws an error saying that it can't be installed on Win7.

Body:

> The operating system on this computer or its services pack level does
>   not meet the minimum requirements of SQL server 2016. To determine the
>   minimum required operating system supported...

I can remove all components **except** SQL Server 2016 and SQL Management Studio, so how do I remove those?

Comment: Where do you downloaded SSMS? According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt238290.aspx, Windows 7 SP1 is supported.

Comment: It could be some components have been removed, it relied on. So it could be interesting if you try to run an install/repair on it, as it might fail due to a lack of components that it also needs to uninstall.

Comment: I downloaded it from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Allan S. Hansen . I will try it!

Comment: It would be nice if you review my awnser as I had the same problem.

Comment: You can refer to this solution([http://serverfault.com/questions/798902/how-can-i-uninstall-sql-server-2016-ctp3-3-from-windows-7-and-bypass-the-uninst](http://serverfault.com/questions/798902/how-can-i-uninstall-sql-server-2016-ctp3-3-from-windows-7-and-bypass-the-uninst)).

Comment: You can refer to this solution([http://serverfault.com/questions/798902/how-can-i-uninstall-sql-server-2016-ctp3-3-from-windows-7-and-bypass-the-uninst](http://serverfault.com/questions/798902/how-can-i-uninstall-sql-server-2016-ctp3-3-from-windows-7-and-bypass-the-uninst)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [amazing article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/) that will tell you how to seamlessly remove all the remainders of SQL Server.

Everything you need is a little `PowerShell script` for generating a `batch file` that "knows" how to uninstall SQL Server Components.

By the end of reading the article you will get something like this:

```
# PowerShell
$a = c:\temp\msiinv.exe -s | Select-String "SQL Server" -Context 0,1
$a = $a -replace "Product code: ","msiexec /x """;
$a = $a -replace ">", "rem";
$a = $a -replace "\t", "";
$a = $a -replace "}","}""";
$a = $a -replace "}","}"" /quiet";
$a | Out-File c:\temp\remove.bat -encoding ascii;
```

After running the given PowerShell Script (needs to be customized for your concrete case), the `remove.bat` file will be generated which, if run, uninstalls the SQL Server components which are not included in dependency graph of another components.

This means that you will have to run this file (`remove.bat`) for several times until all the SQL Server components are successfully uninstalled.

So, have look at it [Cleanly Uninstalling Stubborn SQL Server Components](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/) and find out how to use it.  :)

Comment: Just to stop people from having to search the web for MSIINV the original author has posted it and its source on Github 
https://github.com/ZisBoom/MsiInv.exe

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall SQL Server 2016 due problem of requirements from Control Panel of Windows, you must notice that, this icon is the central icon of product family of SQL Server and it has no size in list of add/remove programs on contol panel. So this may depends on some product which is decency of SQL Server like SQL Server Management Studio 16 or SQL Server Data Tools 2016.
So remove first any related product and the icon will disappear itself!

Answer (score 0):

Try Uninstalling Other  SQL server components which are not closely coupled with SQL Server engine, like Language pack. 
Try running uninstaller on core engine after that, this will usually solve most of uninstall process errors.